# docker-compose lock my local folder when installing wordpress

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to install wordpress using docker-compose, everything runs perfectly but I have a lock issue for the current folder on my machine when I mount it using docker-compose..

here is my docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.3'

services:
db:
 image: mysql:5.7
 volumes:
   - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
 restart: always
 environment:
   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
   MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
   MYSQL_USER: wordpress
   MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

 wordpress:
 depends_on:
   - db
 image: wordpress:latest
 ports:
   - "8000:80"
 restart: always
 environment:
   WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
   WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
   WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
 volumes:
  - ./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
volumes:
  db_data:
```

and here is how the folder is locked

[image]

The owner of wp-content is not the root, this happened because it's created using the docker-compose, I tried to change the owner but the connection to db failed!

Answer (score 0):

as you can see there is a shared volume between the container and the folder:

```
 volumes:
  - ./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
```

you can stop the container in order to change folders contents

Comment: Even if I make docker-compose down the folder still locked

Answer (score 0):

After you stop container: 
`sudo chown -R <username>:<username> folder_name/`

Answer (score 0):

We run the docker compose file that adds the volume data in your local folder with the owner of the content being systemadmin. So, this folder is locked. Please, change the owner of the folder and then you can access the content. Remove the lock symbol too.

```
sudo chown -R hostname:hostname folder_name
```